# Linux Mint - Apache 2.4 .htaccess rewriteRule does not work

Tags: linux, php, apache-2.4, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a site using .htaccess to rewrite rules but some do not work.

This is my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
# Inicio
RewriteRule ^inicio|home|index$ index.php [QSA,L]

# Paginacion amigable
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.([0-9]+)$ $1?pag=$2 [QSA,L]

# Miniaturas
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*\/)?tdd([A-Za-z0-9_~-]*)\/(.*)$ imagen.php?param=$2&src=$1$3 [QSA,L]

#paginas
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*-p([0-9]+)$ interna.php?id=$1 [QSA]

#Intranet
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*-i([0-9]+)$ intranet.php?id=$1 [QSA]

#publicaciones
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*-n([0-9]+)$ publicaciones_detalle.php?id=$1 [QSA]

# Paginas sin extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.php [QSA]

# sitemap
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule sitemap.xml sitemap.php [QSA]

# Buscador
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^search$ buscar.php [QSA]



# En caso de no existencia
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ 404.php [QSA]

# Paginas incluidas en el template
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^.*\.php$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ plantilla.php?uri=$1 [QSA]
```

But I have an error for example when I access www.domain.com/contacto it throws me this error:

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /contacto was not found on this server.

But If I change the URL like this `www.domain.com/contacto.php` it works.

I think this rule from the bottom list should do the job, doesn't it?

```
# Paginas sin extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.php [QSA]
```

Why am I doing wrong?

These are all the modules loaded for my Apache:

```
Loaded Modules:
 core_module (static)
 so_module (static)
 watchdog_module (static)
 http_module (static)
 log_config_module (static)
 logio_module (static)
 version_module (static)
 unixd_module (static)
 access_compat_module (shared)
 alias_module (shared)
 auth_basic_module (shared)
 authn_core_module (shared)
 authn_file_module (shared)
 authz_core_module (shared)
 authz_host_module (shared)
 authz_user_module (shared)
 autoindex_module (shared)
 deflate_module (shared)
 dir_module (shared)
 env_module (shared)
 filter_module (shared)
 mime_module (shared)
 mpm_prefork_module (shared)
 negotiation_module (shared)
 php7_module (shared)
 rewrite_module (shared)
 setenvif_module (shared)
 status_module (shared)
```

And this is my `domain.dev.conf` file on `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@domain.dev
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/domain/
    ServerAlias www.domain.dev
    ServerName domain.dev
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    <Directory /var/www/html/domain>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
                RewriteEngine On
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

It was working fine on apache 2.2 but after upgrade to 2.4 stops working.

Is there a difference between apache 2. And 2.4 in the form of applying htaccess files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> # Paginas sin extension
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.php [QSA]
> ```

Not the cause of your problem, but the second `RewriteCond` directive should probably be checking `!-d`, not `!-f`. The same goes for the rule block that follows.

You would also probably benefit from a few `L` (`LAST`) flags on your `RewriteRule` directives to stop the current round of processing. It also doesn't look like you need the `QSA` flag on *all* the directives?

> ```
> # En caso de no existencia
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteRule ^.*$ 404.php [QSA]
> ```

This should appear last. The following rule block is never going to execute otherwise. However, this should be controlled by an `ErrorDocument` directive instead.

> ```
> Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
> ```

Try disabling `MultiViews` - this is only going to conflict with your mod_rewrite directive to internally rewrite the request with a `.php` extension (which is effectively what `MutliViews` does). Either remove this in your `VirtualHost` or disable it in .htaccess:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

> Is there a difference between apache 2. And 2.4 in the form of applying htaccess files

Not in the context of your question at least.

Comment: Thank you very much man!!! Removing the MultiViews works:
 Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews.

Can you explain me better what does the MultiViews option do and how it conflicts with mod_rewrite please

Comment: To be honest I'm not sure exactly why `MultiViews` would cause this specific issue without examining your debug logs (I suspect it might be a combination of the missing `L` flags?), however, it is a common cause of such problems/conflicts with mod_rewrite. What `MultiViews` (part of mod_negotiation) does is when you make a request for a non-existent file in a directory that exists (in this case the root), it will try to match an existing file by trying various file extensions (of files that would return the appropriate Content-Type).

Comment: cont... If an appropriate file is found, the request is internally rewritten. However, this happens _before_ mod_rewrite gets a chance to handle the request, so in the case of a request for `/contacto` (where `/contacto.php` exists as a physical file) your mod_rewrite ruleset to rewrite to `$1.php` will never happen.